# argument principle and evaluation of a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be the integral $$ F(t)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} e^{st} \frac{f'(s)}{f(s)} \, ds,$$

then $ F(t)= \sum_{\text{zeros}}e^{a_{n}t} - \sum_{\text{poles}}e^{a_{n}t} ,$

however is the same valid for

$$ G(t)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} e^{st} e^{s}\frac{f'(e^{s})}{f(e^{s})} ds.$$

I guess that in the second case we should take a sum over the zeros and poles of $ f(e^{s}) $ by using the formula $ \log|a_{n}|+i\arg(a_{n})+2\pi n.$

Am I right?

Comment: Notice that $\sum_\mbox{poles}$ looks different from $\sum_\text{poles}$.  The former is coded as \sum_\mbox{poles} and the latter as \sum_\text{poles}.  I changed the former to the latter.  Can you tell me where you found it suggested that \mbox{} should be used?  I've seen that here before.  The actual purpose of \mbox{} is to prevent line-breaks when $\LaTeX$ is used in the normal way, as opposed to the way it's used on web pages, such as this.

Comment: ok Michael, thanks for the edit :)